# How to add Add frontend product url column to admin product grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, product-urls, product-grid

I'm trying to add a column on the product grid with the product frontend url.. I had added the grid by the below codes,

**etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting">
    <plugin name="products_grid_collection"/>
</type>
<type name="ProductGrid"> 
<arguments>
    <argument name="frontUrlModel" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Framework\Url</argument>
</arguments>
</type>
```

**etc/adminhtml/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="SouqTime_ProductViewToProductGrid" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
```

**Ui\Component\Columns\ProductGrid.php**

```
<?php
namespace SouqTime\ProductViewToProductGrid\Ui\Component\Columns;


use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class ProductGrid extends Column
{
protected $_storeManager;


public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $components = [], array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_storeManager  = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}


public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
         $obManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
         $target    = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
         $stManager = $obManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'); 
         $fieldName = $this->getData("name"); 
         foreach ($dataSource["data"]["items"] as $key => $item)  {

          $product=$stManager->load($item["entity_id"]);
          $url_key = $product->getUrlInStore();

          $dataSource["data"]["items"][$key][$fieldName] = $url_key;

        }


    }

    return $dataSource;
}


}
```

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="
  urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="product_columns">
    <column name="preview" class="SouqTime\ProductViewToProductGrid\Ui\Component\Columns\ProductGrid">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">View</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>     
</listing>
```

Now,Above code return the first product's url to all products like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9nkG.jpg

Please Anyone help me to fix this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Anyone Help me to solve this.. :(

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if not solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I had solved by this way..**

```
<?php
namespace SouqTime\ProductViewToProductGrid\Ui\Component\Columns;


use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class ProductGrid extends Column
{
protected $_storeManager;


public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $components = [], array $data = []
)
{

    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);

    $this->_storeManager  = $storeManager;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->product = $this->productFactory->create();

}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource["data"]["items"])) {
        $fieldName = $this->getData("name"); 
        $obManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $stManager = $obManager->get("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product");

        foreach ($dataSource["data"]["items"] as $key => $item)  {

          $storeId = 1;
          $product = $obManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById($item['entity_id'], false, $storeId);
           $url =  $product->setStoreId($storeId)->getUrlModel()->getUrlInStore($product, ['_escape' => true]);
           $html = "<a target='_blank' href=" .$url. ">";
           $html .=  "view";
           $html .= "</a>"; 
           $dataSource["data"]["items"][$key][$fieldName] =  $html;
        }   
    }

    return $dataSource;
}


}
```